# Facebook getting response from log-in

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am trying to implement a Facebook log-in feature, where the user clicks the Facebook image, the FB SDK does its thing (logging the user in or asking for permissions, etc.) then afterwards I would like to auto-fill some form fields with the response.

Here is my code:

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src =     "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=[appid]&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-onlogin="logFBResponse();" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false"></div>
```

I added the `onlogin="logFBResponse();"` and created that JS function, but how do I get the user response object? At the very least I would like the user's name and e-mail address.

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: can you share code for logFBResponse() function..

Answer (score 0):

Just call the facebook APIs and get whatever you wish to in your function `logFBResponse()`. Just like-

```
function logFBResponse() {
   FB.api('/me', function(response) {
     alert('Yo ' + response.name + '!');
   });
}
```

To get the **email**, you need to add `scope` parameter in the login button, eg: `scope="email"`

Relevant documentations you can go through-

- [Using Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2)
- [Graph API Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/)

Comment: what if you're using this in angular? how would you call it? `data-onlogin="{{logFBResponse}}"`?